# Python regex: Match any text excluding 2 words (probably look arounds)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to make a regex that matches tags like this (so I can substitute them with blanks):

```
{# This is a comment #}
{% if cows > pandas %}
{{ my_variable }}
```

However if the first word in the tags is `includes` or `extends` then it must not match the tag (it will always be paired with `{% %}` tokens fyi).

e.g.

```
{% include 'foo.html' %}
{% extends 'foo/bar/baz.html' %}
```

I have the following python regex

```
{[{#%]\s*.*?(?!include|extends)[}#%]}
```

However the negative assertion is not working (i.e include and exclude are matched below):

```
{# match this #}
{% match this %}
{{ match this }}
asdf
{% foo 'match this' %} asdf {% foo 'match this' %} asdf
{% include 'not this' %}
{% extends 'not this' %}
asdf
```

Note: Yes this is to do with Django templating if you are interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
{[{#%](?!\s*(?:include|extends)\b).*?[}#%]}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5RlZcm/2).

*Details*:

- `{` - a `{` char
- `[{#%]` - a `{`, `#` or `%` char
- `(?!\s*(?:include|extends)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more whitespaces followed with `include` or `extends` words as whole words immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `[}#%]` - a `}`, `#` or `%` char
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: Wow you are a regex wizzard, and I use regex101 all the time, big thank you Wiktor!